# can I extract only the used CSS from a stylesheet?

Tags: php, html, css, regex, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to send BootStrap based email but since the email do not support external CSS so I need to embed instead only the required CSS as `<style>....css....code....</style>` but I want to know if there can be anyway that I can extract only the Tables CSS code from BootStrap CSS file so that I won't have to collect CSS code portions from the css file manually??

Like for instance only to collect all the CSS of a specific HTML Element and it's sub elements for instance I want to copy only the Tables CSS code???

I retrieved it through PHP as :

```
<?php

$bootstrap = file_get_contents("bootstrap.min.css");

$explode = explode("}", $bootstrap);

for ($i=0; $i < count($explode); $i++) { 
    if (strpos($explode[$i],".table") !== false) {
        echo $explode[$i]."}</br></br>";
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: It probably isn't a good idea to use Bootstrap as the foundation for HTML formatted email. It isn't designed to work with the bugs in some common email clients' HTML rendering engines.

Comment: `window.getComputedStyle(ele)` for one element but not for it's children.

Comment: You're in a difficult position, unfortunately; your posed question ("can I extract only the used CSS from a stylesheet") is good, and on-topic (although it would, still, be preferable for you to post your own attempts, and explain why/how they failed). Unfortunately, since Bootstrap is not recommended for this, due to it being externally hosted and not designed for the (many, *many*) problems of styling emails it may struggle to get answers. And if you revise the question to "what library do you recommend?" then the question is immediately off-topic, and will be closed as such.

Comment: @DavidThomas : Yes..Thanks for the notification...I need the specific informations and removed the comment..! :D

Comment: Incidentally, do you want to do this server-side? If you do then you should add another tag, or tags, to the question specifying the server-side language(s) you're using, or would prefer to use.

Comment: @DavidThomas : Thanks for the guidance towards making my question a better question..!

Comment: @DavidThomas : If you could take a look back again at my question..I updated the question..!

Answer (score 0):

If you use not minified BootStrap, PHP solution will be:

```
$regex = "/.*(table|tr|td)([^\}]+)}/";
$bootstrap = //here goes bootstrap string
preg_match($regex,$bootstrap, $matches);
```

Then, $matches will be an array with all styles you want. You can add whatever you want in the `(table|tr|td)` part, changing it to `(table|tr|td|th|tbody)`, for example.

For more documentation see: https://secure.php.net/manual/function.preg-match.php

Comment: While it's possible that this could be done with regular expressions, you need to show *how* this could be achieved with regular expressions to turn this comment into an answer that's useful for the OP and future visitors.

Comment: Can you write regular expression in PHP for `<table>` and it's all child elements as `<tr><th><td><tbody>` etc

Comment: Just edited my answer, please check if that works =)

Comment: Arthur, when you're replying to a speicific person who isn't the author of the question/answer itself, you should type @ and their name, so that the system notifies them.

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai Does Arthur's updated answer work for you?

Comment: @cfqueryparam : no it's not working so I wrote another code my own self...updated the question back again with the new code..!